# Dynamically generate anonymous type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have an application that deserializes this xml:

```
<SpecialRoutesList>
    <SpecialRoutes>
        <SpecialRoute>
            <Name>TestRoute1</Name>
            <Pattern>TestRouteUrl1</Pattern>
            <Defaults>
                <Controller>Home</Controller>
                <Action>TestRoute1</Action>
                <Params>
                    <Key>id</Key>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Params>
            </Defaults>
        </SpecialRoute>
        <SpecialRoute>
            <Name>TestRoute2</Name>
            <Pattern>TestRouteUrl2</Pattern>
            <Defaults>
                <Controller>Home</Controller>
                <Action>TestRoute2</Action>
                <Params>
                    <Key>id</Key>
                    <Value>1</Value>
                </Params>
            </Defaults>
        </SpecialRoute>
    </SpecialRoutes>
</SpecialRoutesList>
```

I'm interested to use this deserialized information to map each route:

```
foreach(SpecialRoute route in SpecialRoutesList.SpecialRoutes) {
    routes.MapRoute(route.Name, route.Pattern, new { ?????????? }, ????????);
}
```

To set the defaults of a route it's needed to use anonymous types, so how can I use these anonymous types, taking the keys and values from my deserialized class at runtime?

Thanks

Regards

Jose

Comment: The concept of an "anonymous type" is really only at compile time.  The "type" is simply not known by your code at compile time but a non-anonymous type is generated so at run-time there is a concrete type in use.  There are parsers that will parse XML and generate a dynamic type.  For example: http://baijumax.blogspot.ca/2012/02/deserializing-xml-to-dynamic-object-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routes.MapRoute()` builds [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) from defaults. So you may deserialize/build `Dictionary<string,object>` from your xml and pass it to `routes.MapRoute()`. Same with constraints paramenter.

Update: defaults built as dictionary

```
var defaults = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"controller", "Account"}, {"action", "Login"}};

routes.MapRoute(
  "Default", // Route name
  "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
  defaults
);
```

Comment: Hi Dima, 

thanks for the response first of all. I tried to use route.Defaults.ToDictionary(d=>d.Key,d=>d.Value) in order to have a dictionary<string,object> but looks like is not the same than new RouteValueDictionary(new{controller="X", Action="Y"})

Comment: I have double checked this, and it works. I put my code in updade. The reason why your code doesn't work might be in case mismatch of url pattern parameters and defaults.